# When do the values of trigonometric function not change when pi is added?

Tags: trigonometry

I've often seen expressions like: [image]

and I'm not sure in which all conditions this is applicable (maybe which trigonometric functions). I know when 2$\pi$ is added, it always comes the same value, however, I'm not sure about when the value is the same when the expression is like $\pi$ + $\pi/6$

Would be really appreciated if someone could help me out with this, thanks. :)

Comment: It is simple to see that the first is equal to the second, but the second in not equal to the third. Are you sure the function is not tan instead? Furthermore, sin and cos has a period of 2π but tan has a period of π only.

Comment: Okay, so like you said that cos and sin have a period of 2π, similarly, the other ones must have such a period, right? What are they? And about it being tan instead...not entirely sure...

Comment: sec and csc are also having a period of 2π. I mean could the function (csc) was mistakenly quoted. If it is tan, the equality will then be true.

Comment: Think about this logically. Adding $\pi$ to the angle moves the point to the other side of the circle. Both sines and cosine (and their reciprocals (i.e. $\csc$ and $\sec$)) will flip their signs (no pun intended). It's their products and ratios that will remain the same (e.g. $\sin\theta\cos\theta, \tan\theta$, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to to understand how sin, cos and other trigonometric functions are defined.

$$sin\theta = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$$ now this opposite and hypotenuse are considered accordingly with their $SIGNS$ i.e., (+ve or -ve) as in $cartesian plane.$

so $$sin\theta=\frac yr$$ which is positive in first quadrant since y is positive and remember r is always positive.

and in the second quadrant it is again positive since y is again positive there.

but if you consider sine in third and fourth quadrant it is -ve since y is negative there

similarly cos is defined as $$cos\theta = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$$

$$\implies cos\theta=\frac xr$$

which is positive in first and fourth quadrant since x is positive

and

negative in second and third quadrant since x is negative there.

similarly other trigonometric functions are defined

$$tan\theta = \frac yx$$

$Your Point$ : so after taking complete rotation of $360$ you will get all trigonometric functions repeating because of its very definition

Comment: if you understand the above than you will definitely figure out the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the question asked to me ::  Why is that for any trigonometric function $f, f(2\pi + \theta )=f(\theta )$ for any value of $\theta$

I spontaneously said that it was because of their very definition.

Here is the complete description of answer i provided.

Normally we define trigonometric functions for acute angles using right angled triangle as follows.

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {opp}{hyp} \qquad  \cos \theta = \frac {adj}{hyp}  \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {opp}{adj}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {hyp}{opp} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {hyp}{adj} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {adj}{opp}$$

But we can extend our definitions for even other angles using point $P(a,b)$ on cartesian plane as follows

Definition of trigonometric functions as i remember

Consider a point in cartesian plane in $1^{st}$ quadrant as shown

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad \cos \theta = \frac {a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {a}{b}$$

Now consider another point in $2^{nd}$ quadrant

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad\cos \theta = \frac {-a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{-a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{-a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {-a}{b}$$

As you can see we consider the signed values of x and y in the definition keeping in mind that r is always greater than zero.

similarly we can extend this definition (in other quadrants) for other angles.

so if we rotate the line passing through origin and $P(a,b)$ through an angle of $360^o$ we again reach the same point and hence $f(2\pi + \theta )=f(\theta )$ where f is any trigonometric function.